# GKE Autopilot change compute class to "general purpose"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I know you can select a different compute class in gke using the following setting.

```yaml
nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/compute-class: Balanced
```

This part is documented in https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-compute-classes.

I have set this for experimenting, but now I want to undo it. Is there a way to manually change it to general purpose? I have already tried values such as `General-purpose`, `General-Purpose`, `general-purpose`, `general` and all returns the following error:

```
error: deployments.apps "x-api" could not be patched: admission webhook "gkepolicy.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Warden rejected the request because it violates one or more constraints.
Violations details: {"[denied by autopilot-compute-class-limitation]":["the specified 'cloud.google.com/compute-class:General-purpose' is not supported. Deployment 'x.x-api'."]}
Requested by user: 'x@y.com', groups: 'system:authenticated'.
You can run `kubectl replace -f /tmp/kubectl-edit-2874583209.yaml` to try this update again.
```

I still could change it manually by removing taints, but ideally I want it as a setting.

Comment: Just delete the selector.  If you don't specify a compute class, it defaults to general purpose.

Comment: I resolved this issue by deleting the selector and the specific toleration. Deleting the selector on its own does not help because it won't evict and reschedule. I feel like this is an oversight from gke given how autopilot is taking more money to be user friendly.